# CRUD operation using SDK for Netsuite

Tags: web-services, netsuite, provisioning

I'm working with user provisioning for NetSuite.

How to fetch all the roles in an account using SuiteTalk(Webservices)?

Comment: Strangely someone else is asking a similar question where the title matches better to your question with exact same words... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967164/user-provisioning-for-netsuite

Answer (score 0):

There is no provision to fetch all roles using Suite talk.