# User Provisioning for Netsuite?

Tags: web-services, authentication, netsuite, provisioning

I am currently working on user provisioning for NetSuite.

How to get all the roles, departments and subsidiaries of an account  using SuiteTalk(WebServices)?

Answer (score 0):

For Subsidiary:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:urn="urn:messages_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"   xmlns:urn1="urn:core_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"  xmlns:ns1="urn:accounting.lists.webservices.netsuite.com"   xmlns:ns2='urn:common_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'>
    <soapenv:Header>
 <urn:applicationInfo>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:applicationId></urn:applicationId>
      </urn:applicationInfo>
      <urn:passport>
         <urn1:email></urn1:email>
         <urn1:password></urn1:password>
         <urn1:account></urn1:account>
      </urn:passport>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
     <platformMsgs:search
         xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:s0="urn:accounting_2017_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"
         xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <platformMsgs:searchRecord xsi:type="s0:SubsidiarySearch">
           <s0:basic>

           </s0:basic>
        </platformMsgs:searchRecord>
     </platformMsgs:search>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

For Department :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:urn="urn:messages_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"   xmlns:urn1="urn:core_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"  xmlns:ns1="urn:accounting.lists.webservices.netsuite.com"   xmlns:ns2='urn:common_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'>
    <soapenv:Header>
 <urn:applicationInfo>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:applicationId></urn:applicationId>
      </urn:applicationInfo>
      <urn:passport>
         <urn1:email></urn1:email>
         <urn1:password></urn1:password>
         <urn1:account></urn1:account>
      </urn:passport>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
     <platformMsgs:search
         xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:s0="urn:accounting_2017_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"
         xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <platformMsgs:searchRecord xsi:type="s0:DepartmentSearch">
           <s0:basic>

           </s0:basic>
        </platformMsgs:searchRecord>
     </platformMsgs:search>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

For Role: 
    Not able Fetch those records using SuiteTalk.